# Javascript support beyond 1.5. Why is it not there yet?

Tags: javascript, browser

Javascript 1.6 has been available since 2005 (in FF 2.0). Since then we have had quite a few new versions with new features. (Like v1.8.5, only supported in IE9 and FF4.)

Chrome, Opera and others seem to pride themselves by being up to date with the standards; can anybody provide resources or an idea why they have not yet "caught up"?

Built-in array extras and having `let`/`yield` would be quite nice.

Comment: The standard is called "ECMAScript" and all browser vendors are in the process of implementing the standard fully. Those 1.6, 1.7, etc. versions are created by Mozilla and they are not standards.

Comment: Got it, I did not know this. Bit silly to close if over that though, I feel the question was valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript versions are Firefox only code. And it's a proprietary extension that *SHOULD NOT* go into JavaScript.

Go read the [Ecmascript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) specification and see what's *actually* in the language.

[ES5 support table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/)

This question is equivalent to

> IE has been supporting .htc files since 2000 why havn't Chrome, safari, firefox and opera started supporting them?